# How to import functions in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two Apps Script Code.gs and Code2.gs

I would like to import function A in Code2.gs and use it in function B in Code.gs.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If both gs are in the same project, its already available. Else read about apps script libraries.

Comment: where can we read about apps script libraries? What if all function come from another library?

Comment: Just as a precision, as Pablo LION precised it: You need to get the right order in the left side menu. *ORDER DOES MATTER*

Comment: Caveat: whether order of `gs` files matters appears to have changed (possibly more than once). As of June 2022 release notes: "Now, the order of files in the Apps Script editor doesn't matter. " https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#june_2022

Answer (score 15):

Import is not needed. And

> As of [June 2022 release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#june_2022): "Now, the order of files in the Apps Script editor doesn't matter. "

Thanks to @pestophagous 's input

### Outdated old answer

Put the `function-defined-here.gs` before `function-used-here.gs` in the list on the left, and call the function. The order DOES matter.

In addition to the answer from @Zig Mandel

> If both gs are in the same project, its already available. Else read about apps script libraries.

Files in the same project are executed by order in the list (in the new editor you can change the order) like importing a bunch of javascript with `<script>` tag into an HTML. So you will almost ways want the `Code.gs` be the last one in the list (the most dependent one). Also, names are irrelevant since all callback functions are added to the namespace, and later being called by the name from manifest file.

Fact: I searched the document about the fact I mentioned and it is not mentioned anywhere. I myself have decided stop using GAS for this fact, and these [reasons for myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68515040/16223122).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: BTW there's a rumor that Google is not investing more on this.. So maybe just not learn it @PaulRazvanBerg

Comment: interesting. Do you mean Google is not investing in Apps Script, or what exactly?

Comment: Correct. Tho it's just a rumor. But overall, Chrome Extensions has more capability than GAS (Google Apps Script). The only advantage of GAS to me is that it works "cross-browser".

Comment: So how could I use a Chrome extension to add custom functionality to my Google Sheets? Deprecating GAS does not make sense to me ..

Comment: Even if they are doing it, the process would be very long. And feel free to check this: [AppSheet](https://about.appsheet.com/)

Comment: The GAS documentation is frustrating on this. Whether order of `gs` files matters appears to have changed (possibly more than once). As of June 2022 release notes: "Now, the order of files in the Apps Script editor doesn't matter. " https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#june_2022

Comment: I just ran into this using Moment and moment-timezone.js in an add-on and can confirm that order DOES matter, at least it 
does today. Previous deployments were working when tested, but the exact same code was failing when testing as HEAD... I finally came across this thread, moved Moment above moment-timezone.js and everything is back to normal. I wasted hours on this :-/

Comment: @jazzwhistle Yea it's getting confusing like before someone decided the order doesn't matter and now it becomes important again. May your hours RIP