# Error using CardService in Google Apps Script Google Sheets Workspace Add-On

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog, google-workspace-add-ons

I am building a Google Workspace add-on for Google Sheets and I'm trying to show a dialog using a card built by the `CardService` but I  get the following error message.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newCardHeader')

It appears the `CardService` object is `undefined`?

What am I doing wrong?

###### Code.gs

```js
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

const onOpen = e => {
  ui.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem( 'Help', 'showHelp', )
    .addToUi();
}

const buildCard = () => {
  const header = CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle( "CardTitle", );
  const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader( header, )
    .build();
  return card;
}

const showHelp = () => {
  const card = buildCard();
  ui.showDialog( card, );
}
```

Comment: What is the addon type - editor or workspace? Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @TheMaster The error has now changed and indicating it's happening on the line attempting to read `.newCardHeader()`

Comment: @TheMaster Actually, I think you might have solved it. When you asked whether it's an editor add-on or a workspace add-on. I guess I thought it was a workspace add-on but, in fact, it might have only been an editor add-on as I am writing the script in the script files bound to a Google Sheet. And that might be what's preventing the `CardService` from working? Does that sound correct?

Comment: That sounds accurate.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74696713/1595451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary from comments:

> @TheMaster Actually, I think you might have solved it. When you asked whether it's an editor add-on or a workspace add-on. I guess I thought it was a workspace add-on but, in fact, it might have only been an editor add-on as I am writing the script in the script files bound to a Google Sheet. And that might be what's preventing the CardService from working?

So, make sure the add-on is a Google Workspace add-on and the code is written in a standalone script. If the script is written in the code editors bound to a Google Sheet, then the `CardService` won't work as the `CardService` is only available to Google Workspace add-ons and not Google Editor add-ons.

Comment: Google Workspace add-on code could be included in bounded scripts, just avoid using the Card Service with Class Ui (used to create dialogs and sidebars together with the HTML Service)